# California: "For quality assurance, this phone call is being recorded" Can I record them without consent then

Tags: california, lawyer, phonecall, wiretapping

In California, it is illegal to record phone calls without the consent of all parties involved.

However, I called a corporate office and it says that "this call may be recorded for quality assurance purposes" in the beginning of the call.

Now can I record the conversation without me asking for their consent to record since in the beginning it said it may be recorded.

Comment: English is such a nice language. Their statement could mean "we will perhaps record this call for quality assurance purposes", or it could mean "we give you permission to record this call for quality assurance purposes".